# Ubuntu boot not available at startup

Tags: macos, ubuntu, partitioning, boot

I have partitioned my internal hard drive and installed Mac OS X Mountain Lion on one partition and Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr on the other. The installation was done via alt/option key at startup ... **without** rEFIt or rEFInd!

Now, when I restart my MacBook 9,2 and hold down alt/option to select the partition, i.e. operating system, it only shows the OS X partition.

**Is there a way of enabling the Ubuntu partition in this startup without erasing the partition and starting again with rEFIt/rEFInd??**

Partitioning scheme is

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Linux Swap                         999.3 MB   disk0s3
   4: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               248.8 GB   disk0s4
```

`disk0s4` contains the Ubuntu install.